# Angular service constructor blocking unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, constructor, karma-jasmine

I'm facing the problem with writing unit tests for service which has some action in constructor. It is blocking my test and I'm not sure how to deal with it :(

This is service class:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Storage } from '@dvs-angular/storage';

const COOKIE_STORAGE_KEY = 'cookiePanelDisplayed';

@Injectable()
export class CookiePanelService {
  public panelVisible: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.panelVisible = !this.storage.has(COOKIE_STORAGE_KEY);
  }

  public close(): void {
    this.panelVisible = false;

    if (this.storage.has(COOKIE_STORAGE_KEY)) {
      return;
    }

    this.storage.set(COOKIE_STORAGE_KEY, true);
  }
}
```

and this is how my tests look like

```js
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CookiePanelService } from './cookie-panel.service';
import { Storage } from '@dvs-angular/storage';

const storageMock = {
  has: jasmine.createSpy()
};

const COOKIE_STORAGE_KEY = 'cookiePanelDisplayed';

describe('Service: CookiePanelService', () => {

  let cookiePanelService: CookiePanelService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        CookiePanelService,
        {
          provide: Storage,
          useValue: storageMock
        },
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(
    inject([CookiePanelService], (service: CookiePanelService) => {
      cookiePanelService = service;
    })
  );

  it('should set panelVisible to false on close', () => {
    cookiePanelService.panelVisible = true;
    cookiePanelService.close();

    expect(cookiePanelService.panelVisible).toBe(false);
  });

});
```

What I'm getting in console is:
`TypeError: this.storage.has is not a function`

May you please advice how to deal with constructor and how to avoid this kind of situations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> One of the simplest solutions is to add `@option` prefix to your
>   service instance in the constructor in the component where you are
>   injecting this service.

like:-

```
import {Optional} from "@angular/core";

constructor( @Optional() private cookiePanelService:CookiePanelService  ){}
```

I hope this works

Comment: This doesn't seen very solid to me, you're adding code to you component, just to make testing easier? Mocking the injected service seems better IMHO ...

Answer (score 1):

Create your mock as below.

```
const storageMock = {
  has: function() {},
  set: function() {},
};
```

Keep it simple. When you `useValue`, it just expects to be an object.

`jasmine.createSpy()` returns a `spy`. while `has` is supposed to be a `function`

---

Update:

You can set `spy` for the function as below.

```
spyOn(storage, 'has');
expect(storage.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(COMPANY_STORAGE_KEY_MOCK);
```

Comment: Nice! It is working now, but there is another question, in next test I would like to test if on close something like this-> expect(storageMock.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(COMPANY_STORAGE_KEY_MOCK);  so if I don't have jasmine.createSpy() how I can do it?

Comment: Once I set up this ->   it('should check storage key on close', () => {
    cookiePanelService.close();
    spyOn(storageMock, 'has');
    expect(storageMock.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(COOKIE_STORAGE_KEY);
  });
There is an error:  Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
        Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)